# Fractional Laplacian on compact hypersurface/manifold via harmonic extension?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

Let $M$ be a sufficiently smooth compact hypersurface of dimension $n-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In pages 10-11 of [this paper](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/09/09-101.pdf), the authors define $\mathcal{M} = M \times (0,\infty)$ and consider the problem
$$\Delta_{\overline g}(u) = 0\quad\text{on $M\times (0,\infty)$}$$
$$u(x,0) = u_0(x) \quad \text{on $M \times \{0\}$}.$$

Here $\overline g$ is the metric on $\mathcal M$. Then they define the Dirchlet to Neumann map $\mathcal L(u_0) = \partial_{\nu}(u)|_{x=0}$ where $x$ represents the coordinates on $(0,\infty)$. They conclude in formula (3.31) that $$\mathcal L = (-\Delta_g)^{\frac 12}$$
is the fractional Laplacian, where $\Delta_g$ is the Laplace-Beltrami.

So then this is a definition of the fractional Laplacian on compact hypersurfaces (and Riemannian manifolds) if I understand it correctly. However, I have not seen this definition anywhere else and can find no other reference to it, and there appears to be some disagreement that this is correct (if I understand correctly) in the comments of this post. Can someone perhaps clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: The fractional Lapkacuan can be defined  on any compact Riemann manifold as an integral  (read pseudodifferential) operator.  Seeley has proved the most general version of this fact sometime in the 60s. For the Laplacian you can e

Comment: Thanks @LiviuNicolaescu, I will search for the Seeley reference. Your last sentence has been cut short by the way..?

Comment: Yes, it was my stupid tablet that made it hard to type. Check Shubin's book on Pseudodifferential operators.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu Thanks. Have you seen the harmonic extension method for defining the half-Laplacian as the Dirichlet to Neumann map in the case of manifolds? The only source I have seen is the following paper (http://www.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc/c/09/09-101.pdf) on page 10. I guess I can believe it..

Comment: The Dirichlet-to-Neumann operator  has the same principal symbol as the half-Laplacian but I do not believe it is the square root of the Laplacian.

Comment: Hmm. This contradicts (3.31) in the above paper.

Comment: If you have a Riemann manifold with boundary $(M,\partial M)$, the Dirichlet-to-Neumann operator on $\partial M$ depends on the metric in the interior. You can modify the metric in the interior without affecting the boundary. Such a modification changes the Dirichlet-to-Neumann operator  but does not change the Laplacian on $\partial M$. On the other hand, the  half-Laplacian on $\partial M$ is independent of the metric inside

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: that's because maximumtag didn't properly quote the paper. The extension to the interior used in the paper is fixed to be the trivial product metric on $M = \partial M \times \mathbb{R}_+$. They also considered the case where the metric interior is hyperbolic and in this case instead of a harmonic extension they require the extension to solve an eigenvalue problem. (equations (1.3) and (1.4) in the paper).

Comment: @ Willie Wong: This makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between the fractional Laplacian and the Dirichlet-to-Neumann map was considered by [Caffarelli and Silvestre](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2354493) for the $\mathbb{R}^n$ case. This notion is crucial in the study of [nonlocal minimal surfaces](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2675483).

The Caffarelli-Silvestre construction was generalised by [Chang and Gonzalez](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2737789), which is largely the standard reference now in that direction. (One of the neat things in the Chang and Gonzalez paper is the generalisation to other important operators in conformal geometry, such as the Paneitz and GJMS operators.) This has lead to the study of problems such as the [fractional Yamabe problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0579).

For a reference request, the above should give you a bit of stuff to start with.

You can find other references on the [nonlocal Wiki](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/mediawiki/index.php/Starting_page).

Comment: I recently noticed [a survey of Mar Gonzalez](http://verso.mat.uam.es/~maria.gonzalez/Papers/survey.pdf) on this matter which is considerably easier to read (for me).